# Nuget server migration to TeamCity nuget server

Tags: nuget, teamcity, teamcity-9.0, nuget-server

I'm in the midst of retiring an old server we have in our environment.  One of it's functions was to act as a nuget server.  Is there a way to migrate the package that exist in the old nuget server and move them over to TeamCity's nuget server?  There doesn't appear to be a way of moving packages from one environment to another.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet packages are just zip files with the .nupkg extension. Do a file search on your team city server, copy them someplace, or in place push them to your NuGet feed with the nuget command line. Something like this with PoSh:

```
gci *.nupkg | % { nuget push $_.FullName -s http://sourceUrl -apiKey 'apiKey' }
```

Comment: I guess that's the problem I'm having.  Where or how do I get the apikey?

Comment: You get the API key from the sever that you can want to shot the packages. What are you using to host the packages on the other server?